# Setting up gmail alias in iOS Mail

Tags: iphone, ios, network, mail.app, email

I have a school email: name@university.edu with a name@g.university.edu. In [gmail.com](https://gmail.com) -> Settings -> Accounts and Import. I have the first set up as an alias and I can send and receive email as name@university.edu.

I've also set it up in macOS `Mail.app` to function correctly. This is done by going to `Mail.app` -> Settings -> Accounts -> Account -> Email Address and adding the second one by clicking +.

I'd like to have it set up in iOS mail as well.

I've looked online for a solution -- it said to do it through IMAP -- and here is what I've done:

- enabled imap via gmail
- followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQ22euWXYog) tutorial

Summary of the tutorial is:

- add *Other* account in Mail settings
- Settings: up `imap.gmail.com` as incoming and `smtp.gmail.com` as outgoing with email as "user name" and "email" and my password as password

I get errors when I try to send the message -- specifically, it is stuck in the outbox and says the mail server is not responding.

Comment: Can you summarize, with an [edit], what you did here as opposed to making us view a video on what you supposedly did?  Also, provide the *specific* error messages you received so we don’t have to guess.

Comment: Done @Allan. [ placeholder ]

Comment: That doesn’t tell us anything about how. you set it up.  Can you postba screen shot of your settings?  Also, the Mail app has a predefined “wizard” to get up gmail for you; why are you taking this route?

Comment: @Allan it is an X-Y problem. As I mentioned in the last sentence, I have a gmail alias I'd like to send from, but going through the pre-defined wizard there is no way to add it to the account.

Comment: You can edit the settings *after* the account is created.  That’s not the definition if an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  But, if you believe it is, can you give us the *actual* problem, then?

Comment: I have a university email `name@uni.edu` and a gmail `name@g.uni.edu`. I've set up the first as an alias for the second in gmail and have it working the same in macOS `Mail.app`. I'd like to be able to send mail from that account on my iPhone as well. Adding the gmail account through the "wizard" doesn't allow me to add a secondary email on the account, which is how it was done on macOS, following instructions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177653/configuring-apple-mail-with-gmail-aliases).

Comment: There is no answer there @Alper. In fact, that was the original question, before I did research, and found I had to set up IMAP, which is not working.

Comment: As previously requested here in Comments, please add the content of your "I have a university email..." comment to the text of your original question by using the [Edit button](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/462873/edit) below the question text. All possibly-relevant information should be presented in the question, as questions persist while Comments may be deleted.

Comment: Put want you want to do at the beginning of the question in detail (don't rely on what's in the title), then follow up with what you've tried so far that hasn't worked. Readers shouldn't be made to scan thru the whole text to find the question.

Comment: You can’t make an existing email address a gmail alias.  Where does `name@g.university.edu` come from?  How did you get it?  The way you’ve set it up in macOS mail, can you post that so we don’t have to guess?